# Connection reset by peer: Lost connection to MySQL server during query ([Errno 54]

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a python application that is querying a MySQL Database (v `8.0.28`) hosted on AWS RDS. The code in the application looks something like this:

```
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
user = 'usr1'
pwd = 'pwd1'
host =  'aaaaa.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com'
port = 3306
database = 'db1'
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}/{}".format(user,pwd,host,database))


con = engine.connect()

query = '''
        select *
        from db1.tbl1
        '''

df = pd.read_sql(query, con)
   
con.close()
```

The application triggers a query upon loading and query returns successful results. However, after a few minutes (2-3) of idle time, I get an error when it tries to query the DB again / establish a connection.

Error traceback:

```
File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 692, in _read_packet
    packet_header = self._read_bytes(4)
  File "/Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 738, in _read_bytes
    raise err.OperationalError(
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query ([Errno 54] Connection reset by peer)')
[SQL: SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.fullname AS users_fullname, users.email AS users_email, users.password AS users_password, users.name AS users_name
FROM users 
WHERE users.id = %(pk_1)s]
[parameters: {'pk_1': 1}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

We're trying to isolate the issue to whether this in on the Application side or DB host side.

https://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/

Comment: `Connection reset by peer` typically indicates a network quality problem. Are you running this on your own computer, or on an Amazon EC2 instance? If your own computer, try testing it via alternate networks (eg office vs home vs tethered via your phone).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am running it locally on my personal machine on localhost.